# web application hosted in IIS server can't be accessed

Tags: iis, localhost

I have hosted an asp.net mvc application on the IIS server. I have used the port number 8080 but when i try to browse the application, I have been shown a message
like "The site can't be reached. Local host refused to connect." Plz help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number like 8081? May be port 8080 is already in use by some other process.

Comment: Thnx bro.  that works @MohsinMehmood

Comment: I have added answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused due to port 8080 being already in use. Try changing port e.g 8081